# `.font` not working on `Text` with HTML attributes

Tags: swift, swiftui

Text can render `AttributedString` with HTML tags using `AttributedString` with the `uiKit` flag. The problem is I can't apply `font` to the resulting component. `fontWeight` works but `font` doesn't. Even `underline` works.

I need the font modifier as I'm using a custom font. Even System font does not work though.

```
struct SecondContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let html = "<u>Heading</u> paragraph."

        if var nsAttributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: Data(html.utf8), options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil),
           let attributedString = try? AttributedString(nsAttributedString, including: \.uiKit) {

            Text(attributedString)
                .font(Font.system(size: 48))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        } else {
            Text(html)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondContentView()
    }
}
```

I tried other properties and only `font` was not working.

Comment: it worked perfectly! had 2 tabs open and tapped accepted twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is stated pretty clearly in the initialiser's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:)-1a4oh) (emphasis mine):

> Use this initializer to style text according to attributes found in
> the specified `AttributedString`. **Attributes in the attributed
> string take precedence over styles added by view modifiers.** For
> example, the attributed text in the following example appears in blue,
> despite the use of the `foregroundColor(_:)` modifier to use red
> throughout the enclosing `VStack`:
>
> ```
> var content: AttributedString {
>     var attributedString = AttributedString("Blue text")
>     attributedString.foregroundColor = .blue
>     return attributedString
> }
>
> var body: some View {
>     VStack {
>         Text(content)
>         Text("Red text")
>     }
>     .foregroundColor(.red)
> }
> ```

If you `print(attributedString)`, you will see that it already has a `NSFont` attribute. This is the output:

```
Heading {
    NSKern = 0.0
    NSColor = kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1 
    NSStrokeWidth = 0.0
    NSFont = <UICTFont: 0x7fb3dcd18a10> font-family: "Times New Roman"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt
    NSUnderline = NSUnderlineStyle(rawValue: 1)
    NSStrokeColor = kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1 
    NSParagraphStyle = Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (
), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (
), Lists (
), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0 PresentationIntents (
) ListIntentOrdinal 0 CodeBlockIntentLanguageHint ''
}
 paragraph {
    NSColor = kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1 
    NSFont = <UICTFont: 0x7fb3dcd18a10> font-family: "Times New Roman"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt
    NSStrokeColor = kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1 
    NSKern = 0.0
    NSStrokeWidth = 0.0
    NSParagraphStyle = Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (
), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (
), Lists (
), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0 PresentationIntents (
) ListIntentOrdinal 0 CodeBlockIntentLanguageHint ''
}
```

If you want to specify a font with a view modifier, just remove the existing font attribute.

```
Text(attrString.transformingAttributes(AttributeScopes.UIKitAttributes.FontAttribute.self) { font in
    font.value = nil
})
.font(...)
```